# Listening for Auth Success From Realm Sync Server

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm playing around with Realm and Realm Object Server and I've got some things working but the structure of it is blocking me. I'm performing a basic login like so:

```
Realm.Sync.User.login('http://IPADDRESS:9080', 'user', 'password', (error, user) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('success');
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

I know that I can then create my new Realm object with the schema and sync config within this closure. However, since I want to use the realm object throughout the application, I'd want the auth process to be 1 step and then once it is successful, create/get my Realm object so I can use it throughout the rest of the application, including listening for events.

If I had some sort of structure like so...

```
- src
-- realm
---- auth.js // does the auth
---- index.js // exports my realm object
-- App.js
- index.ios.js
- index.android.js
```

With `App.js` being the main entry point to my application, I'd want to set some state on it that changes when the login is successful, then I can allow other parts of the application to be available. But I don't want the auth code directly inside my `App.js`; I'd rather import something for that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a more general question NodeJS server patterns.  From what I read, you need some sort of state established before starting the actual application (in this case, an opened Realm).

I would recommend exporting a function from `auth.js` that returns a Promise that eventually returns your Realm object.  This can be cached within auth.js in order to eliminate re-authenticating and re-opening the Realm everytime it is requested.

In `App.js`, you'll need to call this method whenever you need the Realm.  This can be done before server initialization or whenever the Realm is needed after initialization.